How to extract Parent and child items of Agile PLM
I'm writing a query to extract the BOM information from Oracle Agile PLM database. I require all the correct links between a parent and child items specific to the correct revisions. The below query fetches data for all the revisions of child item instead of the actual revisions that are connected to a specific revision of parent item.
How to fetch the links with correct revisions?
select distinct i1.item_number as Parent_Item,r1.rev_number as Parent_Item_Rev,
b.item_number as Child_Item, r2.rev_number as Child_Item_Rev,ic.item_number as component 
from agile.bom b
join agile.rev r1 on b.item=r1.item 
join agile.item i1 on b.item=i1.id
join agile.item i2 on b.item_number=i2.item_number
join agile.rev r2 on i2.id=r2.item
join agile.item ic on b.Component=ic.id
where 
r1.rev_number is not null and r2.rev_number is not null;

